# DbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.ReadDateTimeAsUtc is obsolete: 'For .NET 5.0 or greater use UtcDateTimeAnnotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

```
     options.WithWarnings()
    .AddDefaultRelationalRunTimeWarnings()
    .ConfigureWarnings()
    .ConfigureWarnings(o => o.Ignore(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.
RelationalEventId.ValueConversionSqlLiteralWarning))
    .ReadDateTimeAsUtc()
    .UseNpgsql(connectionString, builder =>
    {
    builder.MigrationsHistoryTable(MIGRATION_HISTORY_TABLE_NAME,RmaClaimStorageDbContext.DB_SCHEMA_NAME);
    });
       });
```

I have code above, updated project from .net core 2.2 to .net 5 and now getting error that above code is obsolete. How to update this code using `UtcDateTimeAnnotation.ApplyUtcDateTimeConverter`? Thanks!